# TSQL - like question

Tags: t-sql

What is a better way to write the following transact SQL?

```
select * from table1 where columnA like '%ABC%' and columnB = 1

select * from table1 where columnA like '%DEF%' and columnB = 1

select * from table1 where columnA like '%GHI%' and columnB = 1
```

is it possible to consolidate the above 3 sql statements into a single select statement

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select *

from table1

where columnB = 1 and 
         (columnA like '%ABC%' or 
          columnA like '%DEF%' or 
          columnA like '%GHI%')
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select * from table1 
where (columnA like '%ABC%' 
       or columnA like '%DEF%'
       or columnA like '%GHI%')
    and columnB = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
select * from table1
where (columnA like '%ABC%'
   or columnA like '%DEF%'
   or columnA like '%GHI%')
 and columnB = 1
```